# openCV Animal (mice) Recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I am researching animals recognition algorithms with openCV, more precisely of laboratory mice (white) and I have not found good references. Much of what I have seen is related to algorithms such as Support Vector Machine (SVM) and Hidden Markov but not sure if this is the correct path.

I would like books references, scientific articles or codes in C++ that focus on this issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Given the mice are white if you were to track them on a counter of a different colour, say a solid colour, a relatively easy approach would be to use opencv's `cvtColor(src,dst,COLOR_BGR2HSV);` and then find the min and max HSV values of your mice on the given background.

Threshold the output to a binary image using `inRange`, white being your mice and black being your background, and use `findCountours` and the moments method to locate your mice and track them.

Source and full tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS_uQGOQIdg)

Disclaimer:This is not my video, all credit to the author of the channel.

Comment: He said "recognition", you are talking about "detection" which is different.